# How to identify files that contain duplicate headers when appending 300+ excel spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, glob, attributeerror

I'm trying to append 300+ xlsx files into one, but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'
```

Error Screenshot:

[image]

After some googling, I found that someone had the same error caused by duplicate headers. This is definitely a possibility with these files since they are created by people who aren't programmers and I've noticed that happening before. But how do I find which files to fix? With the filename, I can let them know which ones to change unless there's a simple way for me to get around it with code. Going through each file manually would not be ideal.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

globbed_files = glob.glob("BestColleges.com _ 2019 Online Rankings/BC*.xlsx") 

data = [] # pd.concat takes a list of dataframes as an argument

for file in globbed_files: # some files have headers on first row, others second row
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='4. Final Ranked List')
    if df.columns[0] == 'IPEDS': # if true, first cell contains headers
        df['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
        df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '') # normalize headers
        data.append(df)
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='4. Final Ranked List', skiprows=1) # skip first row if not headers
        df['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
        df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
        data.append(df)

bigframe = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True, sort=False) # concatenate the data frames into one
bigframe.to_excel("bc_non_doc.xlsx", index=False)
```

So a list of the filenames with duplicate headers would be nice, or to see which file throws the error, or perhaps the AttributeError has nothing to do with duplicate headers after all?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement to do it using Python ?

I would suggest a solution using Com Objects in Powershell:

```
$yourDirectory = "BestColleges.com _ 2019 Online Rankings/BC*.xlsx"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$GlobalHeaders = @()

foreach ($file in (gci $yourDirectory).FullName) {

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.ActiveSheet
$colMax = ($Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns).Count

#Test if A1 = 'IPEDS' to determine headers row number
if ($Worksheet.Cells(1,1).Text = 'IPEDS') 
    {$row = 1} 
    else {$row = 2}

$firstRow = @()
for ($i = 1; $i -le $colMax; $i++){
    $firstRow += $Worksheet.Cells($row,$i).Text}

$Headers = New-Object PSObject  
$Headers | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value $file
$Headers | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Headers -Value $firstRow
$GlobalHeaders += $Headers

$Workbook.close($false)

}

$Excel.Quit()

#You eventually get a list in $GlobalHeaders of all the headers and file names 
#and filter to keep only the unique occurences of headers list
$GlobalHeaders | Sort-Object -Unique Headers
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's not required to use Python but that's the only language I'm familiar with. I'm on mac so I installed PowerShell and ran the script but got a bunch of errors, the first being `New-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ComObject'
+ $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application`  At the bottom it returned the filename of the first file in the list which doesn't have duplicate headers. I've never used Com Objects or Powershell so not really sure what's going on...

Comment: And then I get different variations of these errors: `+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At /Users/bgoldberg/Documents/HigherEd/python_rankings/excel_headers.ps1:14 char:5
+ if ($Worksheet.Cells(1,1).Text = 'IPEDS')`